# Mysqli error show source file

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

When we want to display error from mysqli we use this example:

```
$result = $this->mysqli->prepare($query) or die ("Mysqli Error: " . $this->mysqli->error);
```

Which in case of error might say something like:

```
Mysqli Error: Unknown column 'bla' in 'where clause'
```

Is there a  way to show from which source  file this error is coming from?

Comment: show $query and check if bla is a column in the table

Comment: Adding the query to the `die()` arguments might shed a light too.

Comment: Yes, if I add query I can see more details.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `__FILE__` constant. If you want to be even more precise you could also add the line with `__LINE__`.

> **__FILE__**
>
> The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.constants.predefined.php)

So your code-example would look like this:

```
$result = $this->mysqli->prepare($query) or die ("Mysqli Error: " . $this->mysqli->error 
        . "\n File:". __FILE__ . ", Line:" . __LINE__);
```

Comment: Can you provide how would this code look like in my example above?

Comment: @Toniq I added the code example.